# ¿Por qué me ocurre un error al llamar un Reporte desde el sistema cuando utilizo un IF en mi variable?

Tags: jasper-reports

Estoy creando un reporte y me he dado cuenta que cuando utilizo en la variable un IF para que me retorne el valor deseado o 0 en caso de que no sea el valor esperado, me ocurre un error.

Cuando quito el IF me permite llamar al reporte desde mi sistema, pero si lo vuelvo a agregar me da el siguiente error: **ERROR: Error valuating expression for source text: IF($F{itbisaplicado}==16,$P{Exento16},0)**

¿Hay alguna solución para utilizar el IF sin que me arroje este error en el sistema?[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Jasper usa operadores ternarios en lugar de `If`, prueba de este modo: **`$F{itbisaplicado}==16 ? $P{Exento16} : 0`**

Comment: Excelente hermano!!! Muchas gracias, me funcionó. Usted me ha ayudado en varias ocasiones, eternamente agradecido con usted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jasper usa operadores ternarios en lugar de If, como puedes ver en la [documentación](https://community.jaspersoft.com/documentation/tibco-jaspersoft-studio-user-guide/v790/using-java-language-expressions).

Prueba de este modo:

```
$F{itbisaplicado}==16 ? $P{Exento16} : 0
```

Simplemente, si `$F{itbisaplicado}==16` tomará el valor de `$P{Exento16}`, de lo contrario, tomará el valor `0`.

Comment: Funcionó, muchas gracias!

Comment: @Tejada me alegro de que te haya servido. Saludos.